# Getting user's data, by custom field lookup (meta)

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, user-meta

Trying to get the user's login, by searching for the current user with a custom field value (meta_value). The problem is that i get the same result, even when i try to provide false meta_value, to test the "not found" part of my code. So far i have this.

```
$user = reset(
    get_users(
        array(
            'meta_key' => 'egt_session_key',
            'meta_value' => 'some_custom_field_data',
            'number' => 1,
            'count_total' => false
        )
    )
);


$user = get_users($user);
echo $user[0]->data->user_login;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may update your query like this :

```
get_users(
    array(
        'number' => 1,
        'count_total' => false,
        'meta_query'=> array(
            array(
               'key' => 'egt_session_key',
               'compare' => '=', 
               'value' => 'some_custom_field_data'
           )
       )
    )
)
```